# Link to controller/action/parameters fails with https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller called Public, with a action called Blog. This action takes and int Id as parameter.

If I link to this action on my test and demo server without ssl, the link is working fine. http://example.com/Public/Blog/1234 ~ OK

If I try this in production it fails because of the ssl. 
https://example.com/Public/Blog/1234 ~ Fails

Is there a solution to this?

I searched the net for solution all day, but no solution found. Anyone here having the solution?

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: What's the error? What about you route config?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "NotFound",
                url: "{*catchall}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

        }

Comment: Sorry for the formating of route config

Comment: The SSL in config on a Azure WepApp. Is it here I should create a exception? Or a config for the SSL provider?

Comment: Problem solved. The view was gone in the migration.. Sorry for using your on this.